# Rich text box plugin for Grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails, richtextbox, grails-plugin

I am looking for a simple Rich text box plugin for grails. The CKEditor plugin doesn't suit my applications needs. I looked all over but could only find the rich UI plugin.

```
compile ":richui:0.8"
```

However, when I run the app, It gives this error

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\Users\Shanky\L\tobu\target\work\plugins\richui-0.8\src\groovy\de\andreasschmitt\richui\taglib\renderer\RenderUtils.groovy: 7:
unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
@ line 7, column 1.
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
^

C:\Users\Shanky\L\tobu\target\work\plugins\richui-0.8\src\groovy\de\andreasschmitt\richui\taglib\renderer\RenderUtils.groovy: 8:
unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
@ line 8, column 1.
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
^

C:\Users\Shanky\L\tobu\target\work\plugins\richui-0.8\src\groovy\de\andreasschmitt\richui\taglib\renderer\YuiUtils.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
@ line 3, column 1.
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
^

3 errors
```

How do I resolve these errors? or is there any other Simple Rich Text Box plugin that i can use instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

The Holder classes are long deprecated and have been removed from Grails 2.4. The RichUI plugin hasn't been update for several years, I'd say your best bet would be to tweak CKEditor to your needs.

There is also a TinyMce and a Markdown plugin, but I'm not sure if they are actively updated or if you would have to do that yourself.